# Loop copy file in BATCH

Tags: batch-file, copy

Is there a way to create copy a source file and have multiple copies of the same file in the destination? Such that it renames itself.

```
copy "C:\Users\User\Desktop\file.txt" "C:\Users\User\Desktop\copy.txt"
copy "C:\Users\User\Desktop\file.txt" "C:\Users\User\Desktop\copy.txt"
copy "C:\Users\User\Desktop\file.txt" "C:\Users\User\Desktop\copy.txt"
```

Etc, but this would give an error. Can I use a wildcard in the destination name?
Anything that will rectify this problem please?

Comment: no, `cmd` won't do that for you. You will have to create some logic to detect an existing filename and create an unique filename for the destination. Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+copy+keep) to get started.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. You want to copy `file.txt` to the desktop say 10 times and call the new files copy1.txt to copy10.txt? In this case this will work:

```
SET source=C:\Users\User\Desktop\file.txt
SET dest=C:\Users\User\Desktop\copy
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,10) DO (
    copy %source% %dest%%%i.txt
)
```